# Google App Script multiple if statements not running properly

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code meant to record data in one spreadsheet as a data table in another. I'm finding that if I run a single if chunk, the code runs fine, but as soon as I include all 10 if code chunks the script does not return anything. To cut down the length of the code I've removed 7 of the if code chunks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function submitData2() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2"); //Data Sheet



  if(formSS.getRange("E24") > 0){  
  //Product 1 Values
  var values1 = [[formSS.getRange("B1").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("E11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("G11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("H11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("K11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("L11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("M11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("N11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("O11").getValue()]];
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 15).setValues(values1);
  }  

if(formSS.getRange("E44") > 0){  
  //Product 2 Values
  var values2 = [[formSS.getRange("B1").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("E12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("G12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("H12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("K12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("L12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("M12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("N12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("O12").getValue()]];
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 15).setValues(values2);
  }   
 if(formSS.getRange("E64") > 0){  
  //Product 3 Values
  var values3 = [[formSS.getRange("B1").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("E13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("G13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("H13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("K13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("L13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("M13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("N13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("O13").getValue()]];
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 15).setValues(values3);
  }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function submitData2() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fsh=ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet=ss.getSheetByName("sheet2"); //Data Sheet
  if(fsh.getRange("E24").getValue() > 0){  
    //Product 1 Values
    var values1=fsh.getRange('B11:O11').getValues()[0];
    values1.unshift(fsh.getRange('B1').getValue());
    datasheet.appendRow(values1);
  }  
  if(fsh.getRange("E44").getValue() > 0){  
    //Product 2 Values
    var values2=fsh.getRange('B12:O12').getValues()[0];
    values2.unshift(fsh.getRange("B1").getValue());
    datasheet.appendRow(values2);
  }   
  if(fsh.getRange("E64").getValue() > 0){  
    //Product 3 Values
    var values3=fsh.getRange('B13:O13').getValues()[0];
    values3.unshift(fsh.getRange("B1").getValue());
    datasheet.appendRow(values3);
  }  
}
```